# Excel - How to integrate a column header into a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How do I automatically sum columns B:E - based on the reporting month? I.e. I want a YTD sum that includes everything up to and including the reporting month. The reporting month is the input.

Thanks!

Link to the image [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GP35.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In I3:

```
=SUM(B3:INDEX(3:3,MATCH($I$2,$2:$2,0)))
```

Then copy down.